# Pandas merge with unique matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to solve an issue with merging two datasets. Lets see an example:

```
borrowed_money = {'name': ['Alex', 'Alex', 'David', 'David', 'David', 'Mike', 'Mike'], 
                  'sum': [10,10,30,25,10,20,30]} 
intersted_in = {'name': ['David', 'Alex', 'David', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Alex', 'Mike','Alex', 'John'],
                  'toy': ['Car', 'Soldier', 'Plush', 'Soldier', 'Spaceship', 'Pen', 'Plush', 'Card', 'Spaceship']}
p1 = pandas.DataFrame(borrowed_money)
p2 = pandas.DataFrame(intersted_in)
pandas.merge(p1,p2)
```

**Result**:

```
     name  sum        toy
0    Alex   10    Soldier
1    Alex   10        Pen
2    Alex   10       Card
3    Alex   10    Soldier
4    Alex   10        Pen
5    Alex   10       Card
6   David   30        Car
7   David   30      Plush
8   David   25        Car
9   David   25      Plush
10  David   10        Car
11  David   10      Plush
12   Mike   20    Soldier
13   Mike   20  Spaceship
14   Mike   20      Plush
15   Mike   30    Soldier
16   Mike   30  Spaceship
17   Mike   30      Plush
```

**Desired Result**:

For me desired result, is a combination of two datasets, that will have each name used a limited amount of times only. So no duplication of matches could occur.

```
     name  sum        toy
0    Alex   10    Soldier
1    Alex   10        Pen
2   David   30        Car
3   David   25      Plush
4    Mike   20    Soldier
5    Mike   30    Soldier
```

Alex is mentioned twice in the first list, so it has two matches - Soldier and Pen. David mentioned twice in the second list, so it has two matches - Car and Plush.

Could you please help me to achieve this result using pandas.merge?

Comment: The problem is that you are merging on duplicates, so a cartesian product is performed. [Solution is described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364754/merge-items-on-dataframes-with-duplicate-values/49364824#49364824) Uniquify the keys by adding a column of increments to distinguish the duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for helper column for count occuriences, `merge` and last remove helper column:

```
p1['g'] = p1.groupby('name').cumcount()
p2['g'] = p2.groupby('name').cumcount()
df = pd.merge(p1,p2).drop('g', axis=1)
print (df)
    name  sum        toy
0   Alex   10    Soldier
1   Alex   10        Pen
2  David   30        Car
3  David   25      Plush
4   Mike   20    Soldier
5   Mike   30  Spaceship
```